# Why can't I add each item into this array?

Tags: ios, nsarray

I'm using Parse and have a class of a few jobs with a rating (number 1 out of 5). I want to query for the class and stick each rating into an array, then calculate the average. However, when I try to add the objects into the array, it seems to only add the last item returned by the query, and I can't figure out why.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.jobName = [self.job objectForKey:@"jobTitle"]; //jobName string
    self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.jobName];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    PFQuery *getCompletedJobsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"completedJobs"];
    [getCompletedJobsQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
          if (!error) {
            self.completedJobs = objects;
            for (PFObject *completedJob in objects) {
                self.ratingsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                NSLog(@"RATING: %@", [completedJob objectForKey:@"customerRating"]);
                [self.ratingsArray addObject:[completedJob objectForKey:@"customerRating"]];
            }
            NSLog(@"ratings array ... %@", self.ratingsArray);
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}
```

When it runs, it logs each rating, but when I try to print out the array or check its length, it only shows the last object and doesn't include the other objects:

```
2015-01-05 13:05:00.274 Ribbit[15538:251863] RATING: 3
2015-01-05 13:05:00.274 Ribbit[15538:251863] RATING: 5
2015-01-05 13:05:00.274 Ribbit[15538:251863] RATING: 4
2015-01-05 13:05:00.274 Ribbit[15538:251863] RATING: 5
2015-01-05 13:05:00.275 Ribbit[15538:251863] ratings array ... (
                                                                5
                                                                )
```

So, what's the proper way to retrieve things from Parse and put them into an array?

Edit: As oltman and Jack have indicated, I am re-creating the array each time the loop runs, so moving the array creation outside of the loop solves the problem. That is also my queue to take a break from coding for a few hours and sit in my cube of shame. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're creating a new array (`self.ratingsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`) with each loop iteration. Move this line out of the loop (to before the loop) and you should come out of it with more than just the last object in the array.

Comment: Perfect. I stared at this for longer than I'd like to admit wondering what the heck could be causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are recreating your array every iteration of the loop:

```
 for (PFObject *completedJob in objects) {
     self.ratingsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // HERE
     NSLog(@"RATING: %@", [completedJob objectForKey:@"customerRating"]);
     [self.ratingsArray addObject:[completedJob objectForKey:@"customerRating"]];
}
```

Move that outside of the loop:

```
 self.ratingsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // HERE
 for (PFObject *completedJob in objects) {
     NSLog(@"RATING: %@", [completedJob objectForKey:@"customerRating"]);
     [self.ratingsArray addObject:[completedJob objectForKey:@"customerRating"]];
}
```

Comment: Womp womp. Thanks, Jack!